# How can I get bootswatch theme to work with my Gruntfile.js?

Tags: json, gruntjs, bower, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

### Problem

I have installed bootswatch slate theme into my bower.json. I did this as follows:

- `bower install bootswatch-dist#slate`
- `grunt`

Unfortunately, when my Grunftile is invoke, it does not update my wwwroot components with bootswatch. What am I doing wrong?

### bower.json

```
 {
      "name": "SampleLibrary",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery-validation": "~1.13.1",
        "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "~3.2.2",
        "bootstrap": "~3.3.2",
        "jquery-ui": "~1.11.3",
        "bootswatch-dist": "slate"
      }
    }
```

### Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: "wwwroot/lib",
                    layout: "byComponent",
                    cleanTargetDir: false,

                }
            }
        }

    });

    //This command registers the default task which will install bower packages into wwwroot/lib 
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["bower:install"]);

    //This command loads the grunt plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bower-task");
};
```

### Attempts

I followed the directions given at these resouces:

- [Similar problem to mine, but no solution given?](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep/issues/27)
- [Gruntfile documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower-install) I have grunt-bower-task. Still broke.
- Ran `bower info bootswatch-dist` to confirm #slate is indeed there. It is.

What is really frustrating is everything else listed as a dependency in the bower.json file goes to wwwroot except bootswatch. I was able to get bootswatch into the bower file using bower install, but my Gruntfile.js is ignoring it?

I'm really confused. Please help. ASP.NET5 and MVC6 has great promise, but trying to figure out how to bring in new dependencies has proven trickier than I first thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use bootswatch directly as follows: `bower install bootswatch`

Answer (score 1):

If you add the version then it does install all of the documented assets.  So add the following in your bower.json file:

"bootswatch-dist": "3.3.5-slate",